# Select option should not reset after refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to display list of candidates who took the test. There's a select tag which is used to display the hiring status. There's a dropdown menu against every candidate.
I want the dropdown value to be saved to the DB and everytime I refresh the page open the project, that same dropdown value should be displayed which was saved in DB.

Here's my code
HTML

```
<td>
        <form method="POST">
          <select class="hiring-status" id="hiring" name="hiring_status" >
            <option selected disabled hidden value="shared">Test Shared</option>
            <option value="completed">Test Completed</option>
            <option value="under_review">Test Under Review</option>
            <option value="hr">HR Round</option>
              <option value="bg-check">Background Check</option>
              <option value="technical">Technical Round</option>
              <option value="assignment">Assignment Given</option>
              <option value="management">Final Round (Management)</option>
              <option value="hired">Hired</option>
              <option value="rejected">Rejected</option>
           </select>
        </form>
    </td>
```

views.py

```
    def hiring_status(cls,request :HttpRequest):
    if request.method=="POST":
        hiring_status=request.POST('hiring_status')
        hiring_status.save()
        return render(request,'pages/test/list.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'pages/test/list.html')
```

models.py

```
class Hiringtatus(enum.Enum):
   test_completed=1
   test_under_review=2
   hr_round=3
   background_check=4
   technical_round=5
   assignment_given=6
   final_Round=7
   hired=8
   rejected=9

class Test(BaseModel):
    hiring_status = Column(ChoiceType(Hiringtatus, impl = Integer()))
```

I added below code but it works for the first dropdown menu and if I close the server/output window, it goes back  to default value.

```
var selectedItem = sessionStorage.getItem("SelectedItem");
$('#hiring').val(selectedItem);

$('#hiring').change(function() {
    var dropVal = $(this).val();
    sessionStorage.setItem("SelectedItem", dropVal);
});
```

[This is a sample output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUleu.png)

Comment: Have you considered using Django sessions instead? You could fire an AJAX to the server and set a session variable to retain the dropdown information between refershes.

Comment: Thank you. Will have to look it up. I'm quite new to django, jquery.